# How to receive server errors in AJAX request in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using this code

```
if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            if request.POST.get('ajax') == 'true':
                return HttpResponse('Data Entered Successfully') # Redirect after POST
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
```

I am submitting the form via jquery POST method.

The problem is whenever i have some error like indentation , or model error then i don't get anything back. i had to test the page by disabling ajax and submit via normal method and then i see the yellow django error page and then i correct the error.

is there any way that Even if i get any error i see that as response to jquery

Comment: In Firebug or Chrome inspector you can actually browse even the AJAX response and check what the error is.

Comment: Why isn't your testing catching syntax errors?

Comment: i am building the application from my desktop and making many changes. i am testing myself and in that i am having problems.  the firebug console is also not showing any errors becuse they happen at server end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you could register your own handler500 and test if the request is ajax and then from that return an ajax error response that indicates what happened if DEBUG is True, or just gives a general error if DEBUG is False.

The other options are to either use Firebug or Chrome Inspector to browse the Ajax response, or to setup some form of logging that logs the errors which is useful even when the site is deployed in order to do a post mortem on any errors that might occur.

Django itself has built in logging capabilities, one of which is sending an email to admins, but you can define your own using [Django's integration with Python's built in logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/). One option for a handler for these is [django-sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) which I use on all my production sites to record any error that happens and also includes the ability to override the handler500 to give the end user a reference number that can be used to look up their exact error instance.

Sentry comes with 2 apps, one is the server, and one is the client. In a typical production setting when you have multiple machines serving the same site, you will have a dedicated sentry server that only does sentry. However for a single site having it integrated in with the site is ok.

To configure sentry you'll need to add both `sentry` (the server) and `sentry.client` (the client) to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then you'll need to configure your logging.

Here is an example:

```py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,

    "handlers": {
        "mail_admins": {
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
            "level": "ERROR"
        },
        "sentry": {
            "class": "sentry.client.handlers.SentryHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["sentry", "mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": True
        }
    },
}
```

The above example will still email admins if an error occurs and `DEBUG = False`. If you do not want it to do that, remove `mail_admins` from the handlers on `django.request`.

Comment: i have installed sentry and syncdb is done. now will it automatically log errors or i need to program something in code. because i am learning django and i have not touched the looging part yet

Comment: I have coded as you said , but when i see sentry homepage there is no error there, its empty

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a small utility called [django-ajaxerrors](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ajaxerrors/1.1) which is designed precisely for this scenario. It's made of middleware that hooks into error responses, determines if they were the result of an AJAX request, and opens django technical error page in a new browser window (so the original page which issued the request remains the same).

I don't know how people do AJAX and django without it, but I maybe I'm not entirely objective here...